# why some PHP guy deleted github link to the thematic Erlang answer?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

Why answer about Erlang Web Framework was deleted ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982808/websockets-with-erlang-webserver-framework/16264851#16264851

?

Comment: I bet it got flagged as spam.

Comment: But why some PHP guy deleted github link to the thematic Erlang answer ?

Comment: Gordon is a diamond moderator- it's his responsibility to remove spam from the site, whatever the tag.

Comment: Do you also think this is spam ? Diamond moderator removed project he dislikes :) Nice Community :)

Comment: Answers that consist of nothing more than a link to one's library aren't permitted on the site. You'll notice the question was also closed as Not Constructive, specifically because it tends to attract answers of this form. Yours was deleted because along with being a link-only answer, it's a self-promoting link-only answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow: PHP guys make decisions on Erlang answers. Not PHP ? Just remove it :)

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the language you use. It's a promotional link. I don't need to know Erlang to see that it's spam.  The same moderator left a comment for you to check our policy on self promotion on a different copy of the same answer that you left on another question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion

Comment: "Maybe you should take a look at mochicow." -- very explainable answer!

Comment: Mochicow dead project to stay, N2O deleted. Stackoverflow PHP professional diamond moderators!

Comment: Just use Mochicow for Websockets :)))))

Comment: Normally I wouldn't vote to close a post like this, but with the number of times you repeated nonsense about a "PHP mod" wanting to close non-PHP posts, it's clearly just trolling at this point

Comment: What's with this "PHP moderator" label? There's no such thing. They're moderators. Simple as that.

Answer (score 16):

The question has been deleted. Essentially, it was:

> Does any one know if there is a simple way to get web-sockets working in mochiweb - preferably one that has a high life expectancy?

There were some details about what the op tried, but nothing that indicated where exactly the problem was in the code.

Here is the answer that was posted, for people with less than 10k reputation on Stack Overflow:

> We work on Nitorgen compatible Erlang Web Framework over WebSockets. You can follow us on Github: https://github.com/5HT/n2o and leave comments on http://synrc.com/framework/web/

---

The problem with the answer is that it essentially is not an answer, at least not the type of answer that we're looking for.  It doesn't provide a *solution* to the problem of getting websockets working in MochiWeb.  Instead, it's just a message to the asker to contact you somewhere outside of Stack Overflow. This makes the answer essentially useless to future visitors. Thus, the answer was deleted by a community moderator.  Additionally, as others have mentioned, this can be interpreted as a form of spam, although you definitely did the right thing by indicating you were affiliated with the project. Thank you for complying with the FAQ in regards to adding the disclaimer that you're affiliated with the product!  (Well, you didn't actually write a disclaimer, but you were clear that it was your product.)

Additionally, the question was deleted by a moderator as well, since it is missing a lot of the details about the problem that would make it answerable with a programming solution. In general, questions asking for tools or frameworks to solve a problem are generally deleted, as they're just magnets for spam or merely attract answers that fundamentally don't answer the question.

If you see a post that doesn't meet the guidelines in the FAQ, you should flag it, or if you have at least 3,000 reputation on Stack Overflow, vote to close.

With that said, if you do see a question that your project could solve, it's okay for you to post an answer that *answers the question in the body of the post* and includes the link to your project *as an aside*, as long as you add the disclaimer that it's your project, and as long as the bulk of your answers aren't simply intended to promote your product.  But, if the answer is nothing but a link to your product, there's a very strong chance it will be removed. Hope this helps!

Comment: All links in answer was pointed directly to Code Sample with Chat Room that works over WebSockets.

Comment: Hi 5HT, you're right. None of the answers posted were any good. They were just older and somehow slipped through the cracks. When you posted your answer, that pushed the thread to the top of the active page where others saw it, recognized it as a question that doesn't fit the Q&A format, and that's why the *entire thread*, not just your post, is now deleted.

Comment: Great decision! Now people wouldn't know at all how to write WebSocket apps for Erlang. Keep going!

Comment: @5HT Yes, unfortunately there's [no other way](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=WebSocket+apps+Erlang) for people to find that information.

Comment: Try to write something usefull using results from your search query :))

Comment: The point is that Stack Overflow isn't the place to promote your product. If your answer doesn't fundamentally answer the question, the community will remove it. Hope this helps!

Comment: If something look like promotion doesn't mean that is not an answer.
a bunch amount of people comes to decide what frameworks exists
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109502/erlang-template-engine-sgte-google-ctemplate-or-erlydtl

you should remove also all those answers and questions. Your hate to promotions makes you blind. For you my product is looks like promotion, because you don't understand a value, for guys who looking erlang web framework based over websockets this is only one real choice. all things are relative. I really think that moderator of Erlang tags should be Erlang guy.

Comment: @5HT - If your answer were more of an answer, then it would be acceptable. But link-only answers really aren't answers, regardless of  whether it's PHP, C, C++, Java, Erlang, or any other framework. Having an Erlang moderator won't make a difference, because the goal is to keep the site clean and on-topic as a Q&A site where real questions have answers. Now, the post you link to definitely isn't the greatest and likely just slipped through the cracks. But note how the person answering gives an *explanation*, not just saying "check out my site".

Comment: You definitely should stop talking and start deleting half of StackOverflow with questions "What framework for problem X should I use"...

Comment: Just one more question: how to delete my account ?

Comment: @5HT - Here is some information on [how to delete your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).  Good luck!

Comment: You talking to me like I really post commercial and abusive links.

Comment: Well...you did... Spam is spam.

Comment: Worst community.